# Flickr Iphone app Background image zoom and fading animation

Tags: iphone, sdk, flickr

Hello all would anyone know how flickr manage to make this type of effect on their app where on the main screen you see a background image moving to the side and zooming in and fading to another image its really cool. your link sources for code or tutorials are always appreciated

thanks

PS im trying to implement this to one of my apps in iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Ken Burns Effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ken_Burns_Effect).